# Lua: custom compare function in table sort

Tags: sorting, lua

I have a table which stores file names, such as:

```
1.jpg
5.jpg
4.jpg
10.jpg
2.jpg
```

Now I want to sort it. I used the following code:
`table.sort(myTable)`

The outcome was

```
1.jpg
10.jpg
2.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
```

However, I would like to sort it like this:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
10.jpg
```

so I wrote a custom compare function:

```
function compare(a, b)
    return tonumber(a) < tonumber(b)
end
```

But it came out that: `attempt to compare two nil values`. So how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to extract a number from the filenames you are comparing first. Assuming the number is unique, something like this should work:

```
function compare(a, b)
    return tonumber(a:match("%d+")) < tonumber(b:match("%d+"))
end
```

You may also want to check my post on [Alphanum sorting for humans in Lua](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/algorithms/alphanumeric-natural-sorting-for-humans-in-lua), which covers this and other cases.

[Updated to address the question in comments] To sort by the combination of strings and numbers, you just need to follow one of the options in the linked blog post. For example, to sort the file names you listed in the comments, you can use the following:

```
local t = {"file001_abc_10.txt", "file001_abc_2.txt", "file001_bcd_4.txt", "file001_bcd_12.txt"}
function compare(a, b)
  local function padnum(n, rest) return ("%03d"..rest):format(tonumber(n)) end
  return tostring(a):gsub("(%d+)(%.)",padnum) < tostring(b):gsub("(%d+)(%.)",padnum)
end
table.sort(t, compare)
print(unpack(t))
```

This prints: `file001_abc_2.txt file001_abc_10.txt  file001_bcd_4.txt   file001_bcd_12.txt`. You can adjust the number length in the `padnum` function.

Comment: Very good answer, but if I would like to handle this case of comparing, "file001_xxx_123.txt" compares with "file001_xxx_21.txt", how to modify the code?

Comment: If you only care about the numbers before the dot, you can anchor it to the dot: `...:match("(%d+)%.")`

Comment: Actually the file names are like this, "file001_abc_10.txt", "file001_abc_1.txt", "file001_bcd_4.txt", "file001_bcd_12.txt", I want the result just like "file001_abc_1.txt","file001_abc_10.txt", "file001_bcd_4.txt","file001_bcd_12.txt". Seems a little complicated.

Comment: Still doable using the solution I showed in the blog post; added the example on how it can be done.